# list recently deleted files

Tags: delete

I accidentally deleted the wrong folder with shift-delete. After a few seconds, I cancelled the deletion process, which saved some files, however some might have been deleted. I would like to know which files were deleted.

Is there a way to list recently deleted files?

Comment: Nope. Using 'shift' means "*let me live risky!*" Sometimes a risk bites you.

Comment: Compare the list of the remaining files with what is on your most current backup.

Comment: if you after that did NOTHING you might be able to use a testdisk live session but make that from another machine, not this one. Leave that one alone as any write will impact the results. testdisk might also be able to restore your files.